# Authenticating SSH between CentOS & Cisco appliances

Tags: python, ssh, centos, ssh-keys, rhel

I am new to scripting, so please forgive this question. Having done extensive research am not able to find a suitable solution.

Currently I have a Python script which is required to SSH from CentOS into Cisco (and other) firewall appliances. Once logged in, certain actions are carried out.

Currently, we are storing our username and password in a plaintext file and calling that file when the Python script requires it.

However, if the CentOS server is compromised, the attacker now has access to the plaintext credentials to the firewall and would be able to get the IP address from the Python script.

I have looked at using SSH-Agent as a means of bypassing passwords, however, if the CentOS server is compromised won't the attacker still be able to access the firewall through the Python script?

Really, I am looking for a way to protect the firewall from unauthorized access, should the CentOS server be compromised. I have also considered using obfuscation but doesn't seem suitable. Wondering what options I have here.

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: What is the Python script doing? I take it that it has to run unattended?

Comment: Exactly. The script is triggered automatically, adding to the requirement for automation. What do you think?